# Как увеличить количество функций в call trace при kernel panic

Tags: linux, отладка, kernel

Пытаюсь выяснить причины kerenel panic на arm машине. Дамп ядра приведен ниже:

```
[    5.632773] systemd-udevd[239]: starting version 204
[    6.595872] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 80de1cd0
[    6.598784] pgd = ed56c000
[    6.601764] [80de1cd0] *pgd=00000000
[    6.604730] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[    6.607874] CPU: 0    Not tainted  (3.0.8+ #1)
[    6.611001] PC is at get_page_from_freelist+0x124/0x498
[    6.614031] LR is at zone_watermark_ok+0x1c/0x20
[    6.617015] pc : [<c074d740>]    lr : [<c074c064>]    psr: 60070093
[    6.617020] sp : ed56be20  ip : 00000001  fp : eee77008
[    6.623190] r10: 00000000  r9 : c06ce000  r8 : c06d0190
[    6.623198] r7 : 60070013  r6 : c0e2b540  r5 : c0e2b540  r4 : 00000000
[    6.623205] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 80de1cd0  r1 : 00000000  r0 : ed56be20
[    6.623216] Flags: nZCv  IRQs off  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment user
[    6.623224] Control: 10c53c7d  Table: 8d56c04a  DAC: 00000015
[    6.623247] 
[    6.623249] PC: 0xc074d6c0:
[    6.623253] d6c0  e59d1010 ebffb7fc e3500000 0a0000df e59d207c e3120004 1a000008 e59d004c
[    6.623269] d6e0  e2023003 e58d2000 e1a01004 e7902103 e59d3034 ebfffa53 e3500000 0a0000d3
[    6.623282] d700  e59d604c e59d3010 e7e03453 e58d3020 e3540000 1a00005e e10f7000 f10c0080
[    6.623296] d720  e59f337c e1a0000d e59d1084 e596801c e7992003 e3c03d7f e3c3303f e5933014
[    6.623315] d740  e792a103 e2813001 e088200a e0823183 e58d3018 e59d0018 e2833004 e58d3024
[    6.623328] d760  e59d1024 e5903004 e1530001 1a000036 e798000a e2861020 e5922008 e1a0b004
[    6.623341] d780  e58d300c e58d0038 e1a00001 e58d203c e58d1028 eb137898 e59d300c e1a05003
[    6.623354] d7a0  ea000018 e1a00006 e3a01000 e59d2084 e58d300c ebfffd64 e59d300c e3500000
[    6.623368] 
[    6.623370] LR: 0xc074bfe4:
[    6.623373] bfe4  e12fff1e 00002bc4 e59f000c e3a01000 e3a02001 e79f0000 eaff7986 0063b11c
[    6.623397] c004  e5903000 e3130902 1590300c 01a03000 e5933004 e3a03001 e1a01113 e1a02003
[    6.623410] c024  ea000003 e2833001 e590c000 e590c004 e5802004 e1530001 e2800020 bafffff8
[    6.623424] c044  e12fff1e e92d4007 e59de010 e590c268 e58de000 e1cccfcc e58dc004 ebfffe31
[    6.623437] c064  e8bd800e e92d45f7 e1a08003 e590300c e1a04000 e5907268 e1a06001 e3530000
[    6.623450] c084  e1a05002 e1c77fc7 0a000019 e1570003 2a000017 e59f3078 e3e02000 e5907268
[    6.623463] c0a4  e79f3003 e593a000 ea000006 e59f1064 e594301c e79f1001 e7911102 e0833001
[    6.623476] c0c4  e1d332d5 e0877003 e2822001 e1a0000a e3a01002 eb052a50 e59f303c e79f3003
[    6.623491] 
[    6.623494] SP: 0xed56bda0:
[    6.623497] bda0  ed54aa00 c07484a8 00000024 00000024 c2022aa0 22a03649 00000050 00000000
[    6.623515] bdc0  ed56bde8 ffffffff ed56be0c c0e2b540 60070013 c06d346c ed56be20 00000000
[    6.623528] bde0  80de1cd0 00000000 00000000 c0e2b540 c0e2b540 60070013 c06d0190 c06ce000
[    6.623541] be00  00000000 eee77008 00000001 ed56be20 c074c064 c074d740 60070093 ffffffff
[    6.623554] be20  00000041 ee0fc640 ee88fcc0 ed54a320 000280d0 00000001 ee88fcc0 c0e2be4c
[    6.623567] be40  00000000 c0791d9c 00000000 00000000 c0ec8bd0 00000000 000a0000 00000000
[    6.623579] be60  ffffffff c0d17a31 ed54a320 c0e2b540 ee9dcc38 000080d0 ed56a000 00000000
[    6.623592] be80  007fffff c0e2be40 00000000 00000000 eee77008 c074e200 00000000 00000041
[    6.623609] 
[    6.623611] FP: 0xeee76f88:
[    6.623614] 6f88  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.623630] 6fa8  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.623648] 6fc8  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.623660] 6fe8  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 ed88d0c0
[    6.623673] 7008  ed88afc0 eee7720c eee76e0c eed1e900 eec0e5c0 c0e38328 eee78150 00000002
[    6.623686] 7028  00000007 00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000 00000000 eee77040 eee77040
[    6.623702] 7048  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.623715] 7068  eee77268 eee76e68 7fffffff 00000000 00000000 eee7707c eee7707c 00000000
[    6.623731] 
[    6.623733] R0: 0xed56bda0:
[    6.623737] bda0  ed54aa00 c07484a8 00000024 00000024 c2022aa0 22a03649 00000050 00000000
[    6.623750] bdc0  ed56bde8 ffffffff ed56be0c c0e2b540 60070013 c06d346c ed56be20 00000000
[    6.623763] bde0  80de1cd0 00000000 00000000 c0e2b540 c0e2b540 60070013 c06d0190 c06ce000
[    6.623776] be00  00000000 eee77008 00000001 ed56be20 c074c064 c074d740 60070093 ffffffff
[    6.623789] be20  00000041 ee0fc640 ee88fcc0 ed54a320 000280d0 00000001 ee88fcc0 c0e2be4c
[    6.623802] be40  00000000 c0791d9c 00000000 00000000 c0ec8bd0 00000000 000a0000 00000000
[    6.623814] be60  ffffffff c0d17a31 ed54a320 c0e2b540 ee9dcc38 000080d0 ed56a000 00000000
[    6.623827] be80  007fffff c0e2be40 00000000 00000000 eee77008 c074e200 00000000 00000041
[    6.623840] 
[    6.623843] R5: 0xc0e2b4c0:
[    6.623846] b4c0  00000000 00000004 c0e47624 c0e2b4ec c0e47664 666e6f63 00006769 00000000
[    6.623859] b4e0  00000000 00000001 c0e47624 c0e2b50c c0e2b4cc 6e616373 00000000 00000000
[    6.623872] b500  00000000 00000002 c0e47624 c0e2b4ac c0e2b4ec 75676572 6f74616c 00007972
[    6.623889] b520  00000000 00000003 00000005 000001f4 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.623902] b540  0000036b 00000445 00000520 00000000 00000000 000004b6 000004b6 c06d0190
[    6.623914] b560  00000000 00000000 00000000 c0e2b56c c0e2b56c c0e2b574 c0e2b574 c1e23238
[    6.623927] b580  c1e23238 c0e2b584 c0e2b584 c0e2b58c c0e2b58c 00000001 c1dddcd8 c1ddf0d8
[    6.623940] b5a0  c1e12758 c1e12758 c1e23258 c1e23258 c0e2b5b0 c0e2b5b0 c0e2b5b8 c0e2b5b8
[    6.623954] 
[    6.623956] R6: 0xc0e2b4c0:
[    6.623960] b4c0  00000000 00000004 c0e47624 c0e2b4ec c0e47664 666e6f63 00006769 00000000
[    6.623973] b4e0  00000000 00000001 c0e47624 c0e2b50c c0e2b4cc 6e616373 00000000 00000000
[    6.623986] b500  00000000 00000002 c0e47624 c0e2b4ac c0e2b4ec 75676572 6f74616c 00007972
[    6.623998] b520  00000000 00000003 00000005 000001f4 00000002 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.624011] b540  0000036b 00000445 00000520 00000000 00000000 000004b6 000004b6 c06d0190
[    6.624024] b560  00000000 00000000 00000000 c0e2b56c c0e2b56c c0e2b574 c0e2b574 c1e23238
[    6.624037] b580  c1e23238 c0e2b584 c0e2b584 c0e2b58c c0e2b58c 00000001 c1dddcd8 c1ddf0d8
[    6.624050] b5a0  c1e12758 c1e12758 c1e23258 c1e23258 c0e2b5b0 c0e2b5b0 c0e2b5b8 c0e2b5b8
[    6.624063] 
[    6.624066] R8: 0xc06d0110:
[    6.624069] 0110  ea000001 e2933000 13a03001 e6ef0073 e3500000 01a0e000 13a0e001 13a00000
[    6.624083] 0130  e2122503 1a000003 e3130c01 03a0207f 13a02080 ea00000b e3520503 03a02000
[    6.624096] 0150  0a000008 e1d150b2 e2955000 13a05001 e3520501 11a02005 02252001 e3520000
[    6.624109] 0170  13a020ff 03a02000 e1720003 22035001 22800001 218530a3 21a020a2 e31300ff
[    6.624122] 0190  13844010 e35000fd da000008 e3520000 e3844014 03a030fd 13a030ff 01c130b0
[    6.624136] 01b0  03e03102 11c130b0 13a03000 ea000009 e0823003 e1b02423 01a00002 e3530102
[    6.624149] 01d0  93500000 1a000001 e35e0000 13844008 e1a030a3 e1c100b0 e5813004 e1d130f0
[    6.624162] 01f0  e1d120b2 e5910004 e1a0100c e1a03b83 e0833802 e08303a0 ebfffc55 e1a00004
[    6.624176] 
[    6.624178] R9: 0xc06cdf80:
[    6.624181] df80  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.624196] dfa0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.624208] dfc0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.624224] dfe0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[    6.624236] e000  e92d45f8 e1a06000 e59f40a0 e59f20a0 e08f4004 e59f309c e7948002 e1a0200d
[    6.624251] e020  e3c25d7f e794a003 e3c5503f e5952014 e1a0300a e7982102 e7937002 e7831002
[    6.624264] e040  eb00d580 e59f3070 e7943003 e5933000 e1560003 3a00000e e59f0060 e08f0000
[    6.624279] e060  eb00bd60 e3500000 0a000003 e59f0050 e1a01006 e08f0000 eb1558c2 e59f3044
[    6.624328] Process systemd-udevd (pid: 239, stack limit = 0xed56a2f0)
[    6.624348] Stack: (0xed56be20 to 0xed56c000)
[    6.624358] be20: 00000041 ee0fc640 ee88fcc0 ed54a320 000280d0 00000001 ee88fcc0 c0e2be4c
[    6.624368] be40: 00000000 c0791d9c 00000000 00000000 c0ec8bd0 00000000 000a0000 00000000
[    6.624379] be60: ffffffff c0d17a31 ed54a320 c0e2b540 ee9dcc38 000080d0 ed56a000 00000000
[    6.624390] be80: 007fffff c0e2be40 00000000 00000000 eee77008 c074e200 00000000 00000041
[    6.624400] bea0: c0e2b540 00000000 6b8d0c0d dfe08938 5f805169 00000000 c06ce000 5936e17f
[    6.624411] bec0: c0e2be44 2a30b8dc f15a4cfe 000280d0 00000000 c06ce000 00000001 00000001
[    6.624421] bee0: 00000000 c0debb28 00000000 c0e2b540 ed523580 c07656b8 ed51bbd0 ed523580
[    6.624432] bf00: 00000000 eee78180 ed616fc0 ed56bf88 ed616fd8 c0e58224 00001000 400d4000
[    6.624443] bf20: eee77008 c074e7a8 00000000 c07ca394 ed54a320 400d4000 00001000 00001000
[    6.624454] bf40: ed54a320 400d4000 ed56bf88 00001000 ed56a000 00000000 00000000 c077fbc8
[    6.624464] bf60: ed54a320 400d4000 ed54a320 400d4000 00000000 00000000 00001000 c077fc78
[    6.624475] bf80: 0000000c 00000000 00000000 00000000 0004b4c0 402d6c04 00003ffe 00000003
[    6.624485] bfa0: c06d3b44 c06d39c0 0004b4c0 402d6c04 0000000c 400d4000 00001000 00000000
[    6.624496] bfc0: 0004b4c0 402d6c04 00003ffe 00000003 be8d4534 0000000a be8d4534 00000000
[    6.624506] bfe0: 00000000 be8d4074 402437c7 4027dce6 40070030 0000000c 00000000 00000000
[    6.624584] [<c074d740>] (get_page_from_freelist+0x124/0x498) from [<c074e200>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x14c/0x6dc)
[    6.624608] [<c074e200>] (__alloc_pages_nodemask+0x14c/0x6dc) from [<c074e7a8>] (__get_free_pages+0x18/0x2c)
[    6.624649] [<c074e7a8>] (__get_free_pages+0x18/0x2c) from [<c07ca394>] (sysfs_read_file+0x64/0x124)
[    6.624685] [<c07ca394>] (sysfs_read_file+0x64/0x124) from [<c077fbc8>] (vfs_read+0xac/0x124)
[    6.624701] [<c077fbc8>] (vfs_read+0xac/0x124) from [<c077fc78>] (sys_read+0x38/0x64)
[    6.624739] [<c077fc78>] (sys_read+0x38/0x64) from [<c06d39c0>] (ret_fast_syscall+0x0/0x30)
[    6.624756] Code: e7992003 e3c03d7f e3c3303f e5933014 (e792a103) 
[    6.630217] ---[ end trace 27dfcc79f2dafc3e ]---
```

Система MK808b tv stick: armhf7 Rockchip RK3066 with 1Gb RAM. Работает ubuntu 14.04 c ядром 3.0.8+ собранным из исходников. Соответственно могу пофиксить обвалы системы, если найду источник проблем. В приведенном call trace видны только 6 последних вызванных функций, а какие функции вызывались до этого - нет. Подскажите - есть ли способ увеличить число выводимых функций в call trace до 10-15 шт, чтобы отследить источник проблемы, который явно находится до указанных в дампе 6 функций.

Comment: Пишите на русском языке. Либо размещайте вопрос на англ Stack Overflow ресурсе.

Comment: Так всё же правильно. До этого был user space. Ядру неизвестно, что там было.